# how to query from parent model to child model

Tags: python, django

I want to get all the posts created today but instead of querying from post model I want to query from the Author model. I tried this but it didn't work

```
Author.objects.filter(post__created__date=date.today())
```

```
class Author(models.Model): #parent model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(models.Model): #child model
    title= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    author= models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = DateTimeField(auto_created=True)
```

Comment: Can you explain in plain english what do you want to query for? Querying from Author will return you Author objects(rows) and not posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = Post.objects.filter(author__name = 'anyauthername')


query = Post.objects.filter(author__name__startswith = 'startig words of author')
```

You can filter anyauthor name like this ok or u can query this

```
query = Author.objects.filter(post__title = 'Postname')
```

From the above query u can filter using reverse relationship

```
query = Author.objects.all()
```

It will gives you all author name

```
query = Post.objects.all()
```

It will gives you all Post name